# Scala Singleton not working as expected

Tags: scala, singleton

Main.scala:

```
package controler

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      import Utilites._
      isJavaUpToDate
    }
}
```

Utilites.scala:

```
package controler

object Utilities {
  def isJavaUpToDate = { 
    val javaVersion = augmentString(System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3))
    javaVersion >= 6 
  }
}
```

Why isn't this working?
I have been trought a bunch of differenet tutorial sites where this works no problem.

I always says that val Utilites cannot be found.

P.S. Why does it keep sugesting me to change .toInt with augmentString() when it just breaks the code?

Now this gives me trouble, something about implicit ordering and method orderTOOrdered.

Comment: HS: `if (javaVersion >= 6) return true else return false` => `javaVersion >= 6` ;)

Comment: You have a typo in your import :)

Comment: I have erased it and retyped it over 50 times, and I made the same typo each and every time. Amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by calling `augmentString` you're explicitly transforming your string to a [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps).
StringOps does define a `>=` method, but it's meant to compare strings (its signature is `def >=(that: String): Boolean` )

If you want to compare Ints you should use the `toInt` method defined in `StringOps`.

```
def isJavaUpToDate = { 
    val javaVersion = augmentString(System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3)).toInt
    javaVersion >= 6 
  }
```

Also, unless you need to disambiguate the `toInt` against another implicit that you defined (or is defined somewhere else in a library you're using) there should be no need to call augmentString explicitly. The following should just work (unless the compiler tells you it does not) and it should implicitly have the same effect as the code above of transforming your `String` to a `StringOps`.

```
def isJavaUpToDate = { 
    val javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3)
    javaVersion.toInt >= 6 
  }
```

EDIT: as per @som-snytt's comment
The error you're getting (`No implicit Ordering defined for AnyVal`) is due to the compiler reasoning more or less like this:

- `javaVersion >= 6` means `javaVersion.>=(6)`, i.e. I must look for a method called `>=` on javaVersion that takes an integer
- `javaVersion` is a `StringOps`... there is a `>=` method in StringOps (courtesy of the `StringLike` trait it's extending, that in turn extends `Ordered[String]`) but it takes a String argument, not an Int
- let's see if I have an implicit in scope that supplies a suitable `Ordering` for `StringOps`. Now, since you're trying to compare a `String` with a `Int` you're looking at an `Ordering` that can compare two values with the nearest common ancestor that can contain both `String` and `Int`, i.e. `AnyVal` [EDIT: although String is an AnyRef so I don't really get this part...].
- No luck there... give up with an error that says that no implicit Ordering was found comparing `AnyVal`s

Comment: Worth adding that the cryptic "something about implicit ordering" (OP) is due to Ordered companion object's implicit looking in turn for an implicit Ordering[AnyVal], which one could actually supply to compare StringOps and Ints (to no great effect; Ordered doesn't do ==).

Comment: @som-snytt I tried to capture your comment in the answer (and hopefully got it right, since scala's compiler way of reasoning is often way above my head)

Answer (score 5):

In your `main` method you've typed `Utilites` where you meant to type `Utilities`.

```
Correct: Utilities
Wrong:   Utilites
```

Note the missing `i` :) And because your brain is a powerful spelling correction tool, it pretended like the spelling was correct. The Scala compiler isn't as cool, though ;)

---

Also, for me, the following does not work:

```
scala> augmentString(System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3)) >= 5
<console>:15: error: No implicit Ordering defined for AnyVal.
          augmentString(System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3)) >= 5
```

Instead I replaced it with

```
System.getProperty("java.version").substring(2, 3)).toInt >= 5
```

The implicit ordering issue you experienced with the former code is because Scala does not know how to apply the `>=` method/operator to the type `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps`, which `augmentString()` returns.